# Как вывести всю информацию в консоль?

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Не выводится вся информация в консоль, пишет ... 310 more items.
Каким образом можно вывести всю инфу?

```
Array.prototype.diff = function(a) {
    return this.filter(function(i){return a.indexOf(i) < 0;});
};
```

создал данный метод для того, чтобы сравнить два больших массива данных и вывести уникальные значения.
Можно ли как-то сохранить полученные данные в отдельный тхт файл?

Comment: О чём ваш вопрос? О том как нужно вывести всю информацию или о том как сохранить данные в `.txt` файл?

Comment: Мне важно, чтобы я смог получить этот "целый" массив данных. В формате тхт или в консоли - мне не столь важно, главное вывести эти данные.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно расширить этот "диапазон" вывода консоли

Comment: Хмм, интересная задача, сейчас попробую. P.S. как я заметил Node.JS разделяет массив на 100 элементов.

Comment: Чем вы это печатаете? `console.log`? Это nodejs?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy погодите, это ведь PowerShell...

Comment: нодой вывожу, да, console.log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`console.log` для отладки. Для вывода [process.stdout](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processstdout):

```
data = ...
process.stdout.write(JSON.stringify(data) + '\n');
```

Comment: Хитрую вы конечно конструкцию выдумали...

Comment: все гениальное - просто...
Коллеги, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример решения:

```js
let array = []

for (let i = 0; i < 567; i++) {
  array.push(i) // Создаём 567 элементов массива
}

function displayAllData(arr) {
  console.log('[')

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let arrEl = arr[i]
    let _arrEl = typeof arrEl === 'object' ? JSON.stringify(arrEl) : arrEl.toString()
    let end = i === arr.length - 1 ? '' : ','

    console.log('  ' + _arrEl + end)
  }

  console.log(']')
}

displayAllData(array)
```

Тут я просто вывожу все элементы массива, дальше уже всё зависит от вашей консоли, если она даёт просмотреть столько информации, значит повезло (У меня даёт просмотреть). Если нет, (как на пример тут на Stack Overflow) тогда не повезло.

Можно ещё попытаться всё засунуть в одну строку:

```js
let array = []

for (let i = 0; i < 567; i++) {
  array.push(i) // Создаём 567 элементов массива
}

function displayAllData(arr) {
  let str = ''

  console.log('[')

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let arrEl = arr[i]
    let _arrEl = typeof arrEl === 'object' ? JSON.stringify(arrEl) : arrEl.toString()
    let end = i === arr.length - 1 ? '' : ','

    str += '  ' + arrEl + end + '\n'
  }

  console.log(str)

  console.log(']')
}

displayAllData(array)
```

Теперь конечно на Stack Overflow можно просмотреть весь массив, но это не отменяет факта того что в консоли всех данных может быть не видно.

Answer (score 0):

Для читаемого вида:

```
process.stdout.write(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
```